# jQuery Ajax HTTP Request INTO a click function - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httprequest

My question is:

Is it possible to do an Ajax request WITHIN a click function, with jQuery? (see example below), If so, what am I doing wrong? Because I'm not being able to do any request (I'm alerting the data through my success function and nothing is being retrieved).

Thank you very much in advance for any help! :)

```
 function tracker(){

    this.saveEntry = function(elementTracked, elementTrackedType){      
    var mode = "save";
    var dataPost = "mode="+mode+"&elementTracked="+elementTracked+"&elementTrackedType="+elementTrackedType;        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myURL',
        data:dataPost,
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg);             
        },
        beforeSend:function(msg){
            $("#trackingStatistics").html("Loading...");
        }
    });
    return;
},
    this.stopLinksSaveAndContinue = function(){
    var fileName;
    $("a[rel^='presentation']").click(function(e){      
        fileName = $(this).attr("rel").substring(13);   
        this.saveEntry(fileName,"Presentation");                                        
    })                  
}
```

}

Comment: could you indent your code, its difficult to read like that!

Comment: Yeah, sorry... it's fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your anchor is linked with the `href` attribute, then this may be interrupting your AJAX request.  A similar problem was recently discussed in the following Stack Overflow post:

- [window.location change fails AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252885/window-location-change-fails-ajax-call/)

If you really want to stick to using AJAX for link tracking, you may want to do the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tracker('http://www.google.com/'); return false;">Link</a>
```

With the following JavaScript logic:

```
function tracker(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'tracker_service.php',
        data: 'some_argument=value',

        success: function(msg) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the possiblity that the request might be failing. If so, you're never going to hit the alert.

Can you confirm that the `beforeSend` callback is being fired?

Also, I'm assuming `'myURL'` isn't that in your real-world source code?

There may also be something awry in the `},` that closes your function.

Comment: Hi James,
Yeah, the URL has a real value in my code. 

I'm using other request in other places and they work perfect, but this one in particular is being called when a link is clicked so, I thought probably I was not allowed to do that...

Comment: Hi!

I think the problem is the link itself. The event is triggered and there is no chance for the request to be made. Should I prevent the link AFTER the request? In the success function? or BEFORE?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still wanting the anchor link to function? If not then you can stop the event. See my answer to the following post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118560/jquery-form-submission-stopping-page-refresh-only-works-in-newest-browsers

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing some sort of error is being generated. Try adding

```
  error:function(a,b){
        alert(a);             
    },
```

After 'success'

Comment: Hi!

I think the problem is the link itself. The event is triggered and there is no chance for the request to be made. Should I prevent the link AFTER the request? In the success function? or BEFORE?

Thank you!

Comment: Anything you want to happen afterwards, you can call  from inside the success method.