# POST not working inside click function

Tags: jquery

I have this working perfectly:

```
$.post("check_i.php",  {value: '<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);?>'},
    function(result) {
        if(result == 'true') {
            alert('true');
        } else {
            $.post("update_pop_count.php",  {site: '<?php echo $site;?>'});
        }
    });
```

However when I try to put this inside a click link function, in firebug I can see that check_i.php takes forever, and update pop count is never called (i can see in the database that the count is not updated)

This is my code with the click function:

```
$("a").click(function() {
        $.post("stats_include/ajax/check_i.php",  {value: '<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);?>'},
        function(result) {
            if(result == 'true') {
                alert('true');
            } else {
                $.post("stats_include/ajax/update_pop_count.php",  {site: '<?php echo $site;?>'});
            }
        });     
    });
```

This is all inside a document.ready function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

try `"` insead of `'`

```
$("a").click(function() {
        $.post("stats_include/ajax/check_i.php",  {value: "<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);?>"},
        function(result) {
            if(result == 'true') {
                alert('true');
            } else {
                $.post("stats_include/ajax/update_pop_count.php",  {site: "<?php echo $site;?>"});
            }
        });     
    });
```

Comment: Or escape the single quotes - both will give you the same end result though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using href... then that could be your problem. I had a similar issue and solved it by adding "return false;" at the end of the click event. See this: [jQuery Ajax HTTP Request INTO a click function - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266011/jquery-ajax-http-request-into-a-click-function-not-working)